# What is proper way to save data using Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

So I am able to save data in Solr using Apache Storm. But it seems that same value is getting saved multiple times. Now i am going through links on it but can naybody please help me to know what ia the best way to save data using Apache Storm. I am using shufflegrouping.

Thanks,

Regards

Parag Dharmadhikari

Comment: So use case here, I am getting tweets in storm and saving it in Solr after NLP operation which is sentence detetction . But same sentences are getting stored. So can any body please help me on it.

Comment: Thanks, for giving suggestions. But I have resolved the issue. It was my bad and so changed my code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, storm supports "at least once", not "exactly once" , so repetition of data is possible.

But this  repetition will not occur without reason, it usually is caused by some exception.

You need to see are there many massages fail by the storm web UI. Then what you should check about your code contains: 1.Any exception in your code? 2. Are every messages acked in the right way? 3. Is the process too slow , which will cause a timeout and make the message fail.

Besides, you can see [storm trident](http://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Trident-tutorial.html), it supports the "exactly once" handling.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your [Solr index is using a unique ID](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey). For your situation you have two options:

- Specify the unique ID in the Solr document yourself
- Have Solr generate a unique id using data in the Solr document

The first is probably the easiest. You would probably just hash your input to get a unique ID and include that in the "document" you send to Solr.